# StateListDrawable not working

Tags: android, statelistdrawable

I'm trying to programatically set a `StateListDrawable` as the background of my custom view for a library project. Here's what I'm doing:

```
final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.ActionBar);
    int firstColor = a.getColor(
            R.styleable.ActionBar_backgroundGradientFirstColor, 0xff000000);
    int secondColor = a
            .getColor(R.styleable.ActionBar_backgroundGradientSecondColor,
                    0xff000000);
    int textViewColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ActionBar_titleColor,
            0xffffffff);
    int onClickColor = a.getColor(
            R.styleable.ActionBar_backgroundClickedColor, 0xff999999);
    a.recycle();

    StateListDrawable sld = new StateListDrawable();
    GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(
            Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] { firstColor, secondColor });
    sld.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled },
            new ColorDrawable(onClickColor));
    sld.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, drawable);

    action2.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);
    action3.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);
    actionBack.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);
    pb.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    tv.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    tv.setTextColor(textViewColor);
```

However, this is not working: It always draws the **enabled** state. I want it to draw the **Pressed** state when I **press** the button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just in case: Using XML is not an option since I want this to be as customizable as possible (it's an UI library, so I want the user to be able to customize it via their XML)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess the button is still enabled while it's pressed?

You could try reversing the order:

```
sld.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, drawable);
sld.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled },
        new ColorDrawable(onClickColor));
```

Probably the first currently valid state is being drawn.

If you want a different background when it's being pressed and another background for all other cases you can also use:

```
sld.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, drawable);
sld.addState(new int[] { StateSet.WILD_CARD },
        new ColorDrawable(onClickColor));
```

**Addition:** I just tested this and the following test code works for me:

```
Button testButton = new Button(context);
            testButton.setText("Test");
            StateListDrawable sld = new StateListDrawable();
            GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(
                    Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.RED });
            sld.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, drawable);
            sld.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
            testButton.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);          
            mainLayout.addView(testButton);
```

Comment: Both ways of doing it make my buttons always have the state_enabled or WILD_CARD state even if I'm pressing it.

Comment: I justed tested this myself and it definitely works for me. If you use a custom button view, maybe you should investigate if it never gets into the pressed state for some reason? Also take note that the pressed-drawable only appears while you are pressing down the button with your finger. The moment you release the finger from the button, the button is no longer pressed and thus the default background is drawn again.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get it to work. However, whenever I touch the button, the whole parent layout gets pressed. I'm using the same sld as the drawable for all the view children in that layout, is that the problem?

Comment: You should definitely use a separate sld for every view. Otherwise the sld will be triggered by one of your views and than be redrawn on every view that uses it.

Comment: OK, it's working on ICS :) however, I still have the same issue on Gingerbread. and this project is a UI library so I really need to get it working there.

Comment: Super important: *first* valid state gets drawn.  As dictated by the order that you add them.  (Adding the empty state first is a recipe for pain and suffering).

Comment: that was my problem too: adding `state_enabled` before `state_pressed` will cause the pressed state to never be shown !

Answer (score 0):

The order matters. Leave the Default state definition for last
This won't work:

```
            stateListDrawable.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD,  ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW))
            stateListDrawable.addState(statePressedDrawable,  ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE))
```

```
            stateListDrawable.addState(statePressedDrawable,  ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW))
            stateListDrawable.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD,  ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE))
```